# Ruby on Rails error message in log meaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made the blog app from this tutorial: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

using Cloud9's developer environment. After making the blog, I pushed it to Heroku, but found a problem: my links do not work.

Whenever I click on the link, this pops up instead: 
[image: error message]

When I go to my error log within the app, this is what I get:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 144.162.213.240 at 2016-02-15 16:41:18 +0000
Cannot render console from 144.162.213.240! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (153.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 207ms (Views: 205.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Here is the code:

APPLICATION_CONTROLLER

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

ARTICLES_CONTROLLER

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

WECLOME_CONTROLLER

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

EDIT.HTML.ERB

```
<h1>Editing article</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: article_path(@article), method: :patch do     |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

INDEX.HTML.ERB

```
<h1>Janke Chat</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'SHOW', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'EDIT', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'DESTROY', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table><br>

<%= link_to 'POSTS', controller: 'articles' %> |
<%= link_to 'NEW POST', new_article_path %> |
<a href = "https://fathomless-beyond-24190.herokuapp.com">HOME</a>
```

NEW.HTML.ERB

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><br>
          <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<a href = "http://recipemanager-janaaron97.c9users.io">Go back home</a>
```

SHOW.HTML.ERB

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'POSTS', controller: 'articles' %> |
<%= link_to 'NEW POST', new_article_path %> |
<%= link_to 'EDIT', edit_article_path(@article) %><br><br>
<a href = "http://recipemanager-janaaron97.c9users.io">HOME</a>
```

Also, here is a link to my site: 
https://fathomless-beyond-24190.herokuapp.com

Thanks!

Comment: Need more information - post the code in the index view. You may have a typo and its a bit much to expect someone to read that whole article.

Comment: Ok one sec...I'll change the question

Comment: btw, do you have any articles in your d/b?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @margo , I'm kinda new at this

Comment: The `Cannot render console` message is coming from the web_console gem, which makes me think you might be running in dev mode. Something might be misconfigured with your host.

Comment: My host is Heroku, so do you know of any issues that Heroku has in this area?

Comment: If you havent created any articles in the database, the line in index.html.erb, <% @articles.each do |article| %> will throw an error. What do the logs show when you visit the new link? When you deployed to Heroku, did you run the migrations?

Comment: As Greg W was saying it looks like it is running in development mode.  From what I gather is in development mode it wants the incoming IP to be development probably for security reasons.  Make sure you are using Heroku in production see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments